# Using Visual Studio or Resharper, can I jump to the .aspx page while in the code behind?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Using Visual Studio or Resharper, can I jump to the .aspx page while in the code behind?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess it is F7 or Shift + F7 (that toggles between code view and design view).

Comment: Code view vs. Design view is different from code behind (.aspx.cs) vs .aspx

Answer (score 0):

It will be possibly (and even more) with new feature "Go To Related Files" coming in new ReSharper 5 version.